# Submit Form Contents to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I'll be honest, I don't really know what the best approach here is. I've got no Javascript knowledge, but I don't think should be necessary here...It's stupidly simple.

I have a simple form. I want the user to be able to type a word and press enter or click "submit." When "X" is entered, I want them to be redirected to 'www.MyURL.com/X.html'. The only solution I could find looked like this:

```
<form>
<input name="solution" type="text" id="solution" maxlength="10" /><br />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="window.location='http://www.MYURL.com/' + this.form.solution.value + '.html'"/>
</form>
```

However, this doesn't allow the user to hit Enter to submit the form. I tried the below to make it a submit input, but I don't know anything about the potential operations of "onsubmit", and this one isn't working.

```
<form onsubmit="window.location='http://www.MYURL.com/' + this.form.solution.value + '.html'">
<input name="solution" type='text' id="solution" maxlength="10" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Should I be using "action=" for this event? And I don't know if "method=" plays into it.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to make the form submit its text content to a URL and then link to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in javascript without a form. Just check the key code with each keyboard press - if it's the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (13), then do your redirect.

Here's a full working page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="solution" onkeyup="doSomething(event);">
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="redirect();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            redirect();
        }
    }

    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.MYURL.com/"
            + document.getElementById("solution").value
            + ".html";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, but I'm not sure how to organize this. It's not doing anything when I put the "onkeyup" in either of the input tags (right now submitting the form gives "www.MyURL.com/?solution=X"). It also doesn't take into account the fact that I'd still like the submit button to be clickable. Overall my issue is that I can't figure out how to make the form submit its text content to a URL and then link to that url.

Comment: You won't be able to submit the form like normal - a normal form submission would take the inputs and add them as key-value pairs onto the query string or the post values - it can't actually change the target without javascript. And since you have to use javascript anyway, you might as well let it do everything. I'll revise with a full page that works with Enter or the button click.

Comment: Thanks for the help, man. Can't be sure why, but hitting "enter" still just leads to "www.MyURL.com/?solution=X". I'm realizing that this solution may not be what I need regardless. Do you know if there's a way to script something like: On submit, if "solution" value = "XXX" then redirect to "www.MyURL.com/Correct.html"; if "solution" value does not = "XXX" then redirect to "www.MyURL.com/Incorrect.html". Sort of like a singular password to allow access to the link. Sorry to be annoying, I'm not sure how to search for such a thing on Google...

Comment: Take the value of 'solution' through "var solution = document.getElementById('solution').value", then "if (solution == "XXX"), and if it's success "window.location.href = 'http://correct'", if not "incorrect"

Comment: Have it working other than not being sure how to do the two separate directs. What's the Javascript for "if success" and "if not"? I got the "enter" key press to work, I think it wasn't because you had a third "=" before 13. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @DiegoPino has the answer to that question - it's a simple `if` statement at that point. One thing if you haven't already - make sure you remove the form if you're going to do it this way. I think you were seeing the problem of your form actually submitting rather than the javascript event firing - going with a full javascript solution, you want to make sure there's no form there to confuse things.